# For Loop Stops After Only 10 Iterations Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, for-loop

Good evening,
   I was wondering if someone could please provide insight into a problem I'm having. I've written a simple for loop, but it keeps stopping after only 10 iterations. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you. Below is my code:

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

directory1 = pd.read_csv('/media/Thesis_Maps//testing/JM_rev5.csv', header=None, skiprows=[-1], encoding='utf-8')

results = np.zeros((len(directory_DOE), 3) )

for i in directory1:
    x1=directory1.iloc[i,1]
    y1=x1+5
    results[i,0] = y1
```

Comment: Please print directory1.shape

Comment: I typed in "k1=directory1.shape" and got a value of (200,10).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I suspect that the issue is due to the fact that `for i in directory1:` iterates over columns. Is the loop even necessary here?

Comment: `pandas` works different then you expect. It iterates columns and you have 10 columns. You would have to use `for i in range(len(directory1)):` to get 200 iteration. Or maybe better use `for index, row in directory1.iterrows(): y1 = row[1] + 5` OR without iteration `results[:,0] = directory1[1] + 5`

Comment: That worked! using "for i in range(len(directory1)):" fixed it, it now iterates over all 200 rows. Thank you good sir or mam :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `pandas` iterates columns, not rows.

You would have to use `directory1.iterrows()` (or similar functions)

```
for index, row in directory1.iterrows():
    results[index, 0] = row[1] + 5
```

but you can do the same without iteration

```
results[:,0] = directory1[1] + 5
```

---

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(1) # random will create always the same values

directory1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(10)] for x in range(200)],
)

print('shape:', directory1.shape)
print(directory1.head())

# ----

results = np.zeros((len(directory1), 3))

for index, row in directory1.iterrows():
    results[index, 0] = row[1] + 5

print(results[:5])

# ---    

results = np.zeros((len(directory1), 3))

results[:,0] = directory1[1] + 5

print(results[:5])
```

Result

```
shape: (200, 10)

   0   1  2   3  4  5  6   7   8  9
0  2   9  1   4  1  7  7   7  10  6
1  3   1  7   0  6  6  9   0   7  4
2  3   9  1   5  0  0  0  10   8  0
3  6  10  3   6  0  8  3   7   7  8
4  3   5  3  10  3  7  4   0   6  8

# ---    

[[14.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.]
 [14.  0.  0.]
 [15.  0.  0.]
 [10.  0.  0.]]

# ---    

[[14.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  0.  0.]
 [14.  0.  0.]
 [15.  0.  0.]
 [10.  0.  0.]]
```